# Proving certain aspects of Entropy

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

I am trying to prove three properties of entropy.

$1)$ $H(X|Y,Z)\le H(X|Y)$

$2)$ $H(X|Y,Z)\le H(X,Y)$

$3)$ $H(X,Y,Z)+H(Y)\le H(X,Y)+H(Y,Z)$

I have proved the third one, but it is based on part 1.

Should I break them down into summations or should I have to use basic properties of entropy such as the chain rule?

Comment: You are missing a right "$" on the third inequality I think.

Answer (score 1):

On the left side you have:

$$H(X,Y,Z) +H(Y)= 2 H(Y) + H(X,Z|Y)$$

And on the right:

$$H(X,Y) +H(Y,Z)  = H(X|Y) +H(Y)  + H(Z|Y) +H(Y) $$

But  $H(X,Z|Y) \le H(X|Y) + H(Z|Y)$ - just a conditioned version of the property $H(A,B) \le  H(A)+H(B)$

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Probably the shortest argument is through definition of mutual information which is $\geq 0$. Then the first follows from the definition of conditional mutual information.
$$
H(X|Y,Z) = H(X|Y) - I(X;Z|Y)
$$
which implies (1) and (1) implies (2) by definition of chain rule.

Another way to show (1) is with chain rule inequality
\begin{align}
H(X_1,\ldots,X_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} H(X_i|X_{1},\ldots,X_{i-1}) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n H(X_i)
\end{align}
i.e. (you can think of this as sum of entropy given everything you seen before) $$
H(X,Y,Z)=H(X)+H(Y|X)+H(Z|Y,X)$$

and

\begin{align}
H(X,Y|Z) &= E[-\log P(X,Y|Z)] \\ 
&= E[-\log P(X|Y,Z)P(Y|Z)] \\
&= E[-\log P(X|Y,Z)] + E[-\log P(Y|Z)] \\
&= H(X|Y,Z) + H(Y|Z)
\end{align}
Convince yourself that 
$$
H(X|Y,Z)=H(X,Y|Z)-H(Y|Z)=H(X,Z|Y)-H(Z|Y)
$$

Then we have
$$
H(X|Y,Z)=H(X,Z|Y)-H(Z|Y)\leq H(X|Y)+H(Z|Y)-H(Z|Y) = H(X|Y) \leq H(X,Y)
$$

Comment: what do you mean by I in the first equation?

Comment: That is the notation for mutual information [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information)

Comment: how is H(X|Y,Z)=H(X,Y|Z)−H(Y|Z), true? I get that it equals H(x,y,z)-H(y|z)-H(z). Can you show where you are getting these equations from? Im not attacking, I am just very confused

Comment: No problem, I updated and made some correction. Hopefully, its better now :)

Comment: could you use better notation in your sums, because I dont really see how it all comes together? I thought I had it. Your logic makes sense, just I dont see the sums that your using.

Comment: Is this better ? I am not exactly sure where is the confusion so I am guessing its the chain rule. I tend to write the chain rule as defined in Cover's Elements of Information Theory.

Comment: Okay. I was able to see it through a proof I did of the chain rule, but I get that H(X,Y|Z)=H(Y|X,Z)+H(X|Y). I am having trouble convincing myself of that part. Is it just a simple symmetry thing? Cause flipping the Z's and Y's make no logical sense on the surface, but I am assuming there is some underlying property being used there that I have not yet learned or forget.

Comment: Can you tell me how you get $H(X,Y|Z)=H(Y|X,Z)+H(X|Y)$ ? This don't seems right as if we assume Z is independent of X and Y, then your equation becomes $H(X,Y)=H(Y|X)+H(X|Y)$ which don't follow the chain rule.